# How to build a binary tree of expected values?

Tags: r, decision-tree

I want to create a model like in this picture
[image]

and make the value of the every node add up sequentially from the bottom (like this: Expected Value = (2/3) (-10) + 1/3 [10 +(2/3)(90) + (1/3)(-110)] = $4.44), how can I do it, I have tried many times

I am a beginner in R, hope somebody can give me the solution